# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/thirdparty/afinal/core/AsyncTask;

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, dji-sdk

I am trying to integrate the DJI SDK into my app in android studio, I have followed all the steps as the guide suggests here https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html

However I am gettng the following error: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/thirdparty/afinal/core/AsyncTask;**

I have tried to run it on different devices with different API.

When I run it in a device with API 19, it doesn't show me any errors and the main activity appears in the screen, but it is still not working because it doesn't show the toast message " Register Success" or anything else.

When I run it on a higher API ex. API 26 it displays the error that I previously mentioned.

Hope you can help me! I am sorry if it is too much! Thank you!

[Here is the error on my run window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k37Kn.png)

**Here is my manifest file**

```html
    <!-- Permissions and features -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Permissions and features -->

    <application

        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">

        android:name=".MApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ImportSDKDemo">

        <!-- DJI SDK -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
            android:value="my app key" />
        <activity
            android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIAoaControllerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name="dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJIGlobalService"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        </service>
        <!-- DJI SDK -->

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Here is my build.gradle file**

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dji.ImportSDKDemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.14.1')
    compileOnly ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.14.1')

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a physical device, it looks like you running in a emulator.

Adb over wifi is recommended, I never had any luck with tha bridge app. You can then have th phone connected to the remote the whole time, and even debug on the device.

Comment: I have also tried running it on a physical device, but I still get the same error. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Anyway dji sdk wont work in emulator, so you better using a physical device.
I think your best bet is to get the sdk sample project on github to work. It's usually updated to work. Start from there,  when you have something that works you can compare the build files
 All other instructions is mostly out of date.
One tricky thing is that they link in online content at the end of  the gradle-files  and that content is sometimes changed, which makes old builds obsolete. I can't se any reference to them in your files, so it's probably where the fault is.